# How is transmission monitored from the console?

Tags: command-line, bash, services, transmission, headless

Normally I add magnet links from `firefox` to transmission via the `GUI`, but also want it to continue the downloads even when the `GUI` isn't running.

I've also [installed](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TransmissionHowTo):

```
transmission-cli 

transmission-common 

transmission-daemon
```

and ran:

```
sudo service transmission-daemon start
```

**How is `transmission` monitored from the console?**

*I don't need a `transmission` server per se.*

Answer (score 1):

```
transmission-remote -st
```

gives information from session regarding total download, upload, duration

```
transmission-remote -l
```

gives information on each torrent. The % Done, ETA, Up/Down . This is probably what you want

```
transimission-remote -t <ID from -l Here> -i
```

gives details on a particular torrent

Answer (score -1):

A good place to start in general on Linux is to try `man`.  The [transmission-daemon man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/transmission-daemon) starts with:

> transmission-daemon is a daemon-based Transmission session
> that can be controlled via RPC commands from transmission's
> web interface or **transmission-remote(1)**.

Comment: I went so far as to send the `transmission-cli` and `transmission-daemon`manpage to my kindle, but don't see anything about how to monitor the progress of downloads initiated from the GUI -- I'll keep looking through the documentation.

Comment: Did you read the man page, or at least the bit I cited? It says "Transmission session can be controlled via RPC commands from [...] **transmission-remote(1)**". That sounds to me like the literal answer to your question "How is transmission monitored from the console?" If not, then please rework your question to reflect what you are actually looking for.

Comment: I'm not seeing **how** to monitor transmission as the GUI provides -- yes, I've read the man page.