# How to use transmission-show and other command line tools to find the status of torrents?

Tags: command-line, bash, services, transmission, headless

In going through the `man` pages for `transmission` I'm not seeing how to find the status of current downloads [initiated](https://askubuntu.com/q/1353318/847449) through the `GUI`:

```
nicholas@gondor:~$ 
nicholas@gondor:~$ transmission-show --unsorted
ERROR: No .torrent file specified.
Usage: transmission-show [options] <.torrent file>

Options:
 -h --help      Display this help page and exit
 -m --magnet    Give a magnet link for the specified torrent
 -s --scrape    Ask the torrent's trackers how many peers are in the torrent's
                swarm
 -u --unsorted  Do not sort files by name
 -V --version   Show version number and exit

nicholas@gondor:~$ 
nicholas@gondor:~$ transmission-show --help
Usage: transmission-show [options] <.torrent file>

Options:
 -h --help      Display this help page and exit
 -m --magnet    Give a magnet link for the specified torrent
 -s --scrape    Ask the torrent's trackers how many peers are in the torrent's
                swarm
 -u --unsorted  Do not sort files by name
 -V --version   Show version number and exit
nicholas@gondor:~$ 
nicholas@gondor:~$ transmission-show
ERROR: No .torrent file specified.
Usage: transmission-show [options] <.torrent file>

Options:
 -h --help      Display this help page and exit
 -m --magnet    Give a magnet link for the specified torrent
 -s --scrape    Ask the torrent's trackers how many peers are in the torrent's
                swarm
 -u --unsorted  Do not sort files by name
 -V --version   Show version number and exit

nicholas@gondor:~$
```

Is this possible?

The documentation would seem to presuppose knowing the magnet link or having the torrent file on hand.  How is that information discovered to then feed to the commands, such as above?

Answer (score 0):

Try Deluge as it got webui and console where you can track the status

Comment: thx, I'll leave the q open for a bit.