# How to backup deluge in the event a crash removes all torrents and magnet links?

Tags: backup, crash, bittorrent, deluge, torrent-client

After killing `deluge-gtk` the torrents in progress no longer are being tracked, as:

https://www.reddit.com/r/torrents/comments/4axql7/deluge_torrents_have_all_disappeared_after_crash/

https://forum.deluge-torrent.org/viewtopic.php?t=54454

https://forum.deluge-torrent.org/viewtopic.php?t=42101

https://forum.deluge-torrent.org/viewtopic.php?t=55904

from what I gather, having [switched](https://askubuntu.com/q/1353507/847449) to `deluge` recently. what steps can be taken to back-up not so much the files, per se, as they're still present, but rather the magnet links and their connection to the downloaded files?

Comment: "magnet links" are links, as the name states) so not actual files and there is nothing on your system to make a copy of. The information from the magnet links (and the torrent info) is stored in the file that is downloaded and can be viewed by rightclicking the line in deluge that is downloading the file (or that is stalled). I would assume asking "for more connection/peers" would be enough to restart the download?

Comment: the magnet links were listed in the deluge GUI -- but they aren't listed there anymore.  This phenomena has been reported by others in the above links.  Deluge lost track of the magnet links and the files, so that there's no record of links or files in deluge, regardless of progress or even the number of peers.  As there's no link listed it's simply not possible to ask for more peers @Rinzwind because deluge has reset.  Deluge is blank after this happens.